# Resize NSWindow with "semi-fixed" aspect ratio

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, autolayout

(I hope the tile makes sense...) I'm trying to make my NSWindow resizing be "constrained" by it's content, which is a view with a fixed aspect ratio, and a spacing at the bottom, like in the picture.

[image: screenshot]

The constraints are, from ContextBackedView to superview, leading, trailing and top space equals to 0, and bottom space equals to 37, plus the aspect ratio constraint (418:263)

Here's the output for `constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation` (0x6000001217c0 is the window contentView)
NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal‌

```
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x618000080af0 h=-&- v=-&- H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x6000001217c0]   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x1003060c0'Window' )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x618000080b40 h=-&- v=-&- H:[NSView:0x6000001217c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x1003060c0'Window' )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000080870 'NSWindow-current-width' H:[NSThemeFrame:0x1003060c0'Window'(418@500)] priority:500>
```

NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical

```
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x618000080af0 h=-&- v=-&- H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x6000001217c0]   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x1003060c0'Window' )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x618000080b40 h=-&- v=-&- H:[NSView:0x6000001217c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x1003060c0'Window' )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000828a0 H:[NSView:0x600000121860]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6000001217c0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000082990 H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x600000121860]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6000001217c0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000080870 'NSWindow-current-width' H:[NSThemeFrame:0x1003060c0'Window'(418@500)] priority:500>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x618000080b90 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSView:0x6000001217c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x1003060c0'Window' )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000828f0 V:|-(0)-[NSView:0x600000121860]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6000001217c0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000082940 V:[NSView:0x600000121860]-(37)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x6000001217c0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000800f0 NSView:0x600000121860.width == 1.58935*NSView:0x600000121860.height>
```

Using auto layout, it only works if I resized the window's width, but not if I try to change it's height.
I can't use -[NSWindow setAspectRatio:] since the ratio of the window is not actually a fixed number (due to the bottom space having to stay the same)

I also tried using -windowWillResize:toSize: but I couldn't find a way to make it work reliably (resizing only width or height is fine but when changing both it usually broke...)

Does anyone knows a way to achieve this?

Comment: What happens when you try to change the window's height?

Comment: It just doesn't get resized...

Comment: Your screenshot seems to obscure some of the constraints. You can collapse the Object library view. Or explain the constraints in text in your question or something.

Comment: I've update the screenshot + added description

Comment: Hmm. I'm not familiar with storyboards and how the view will get constrained to the window's content view (or does the view *become* the window's content view?). It might be informative to log `[window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]` and `[window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]` at run time.

Comment: Seems like the view becomes the contentView, I updated the question with the output...

Comment: Very curious. The constraints affecting vertical include various horizontal constraints because those affect the width and then the aspect ratio constraint causes that to affect the height. However, the same should work in the other orientation, but it doesn't seem to. That seems like a bug, although if it were fixed that would probably just prevent resizing in both directions. Try setting the priority of the aspect ratio constraint to low.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a constraint (Aspect Ration Constraint) to your `ContextBackedView`, with the multiplier property being the aspect ratio you'd like (e.g 4:3), you should be able to achieve what you want.

It's easy if you are building this through IB-- first select your `ContextBackedView`, and on the bottom-right click on the box with lines icon, and select "Aspect Ratio".  That will maintain your view's current aspect ratio after being resized.

If you want to do it programmatically you'll have to look into instantiating and applying `NSLayoutConstraints` onto `NSViews`.  I have never done it with Aspect Ratio Constraints, but it should be pretty straight forward.  If you want a code sample let me know I can spin one up :)

Comment: If you look at the screenshot you can see that I already added that constraint... The problem is not resizing the view, but the window...

Comment: Oh sorry, I just made a sample app and got it to resize; but neglected to look closely at your image.  My fault.  So what I got to work was make a custom view as the bottom bar, set a height constraint on that, and then set the top of that view to constrain distance 0 from the bottom of the top view.  I will double check tomorrow too

Comment: I tried putting another view at the bottom instead of leaving the space empty, but it doesn't seem to matter (unless by bottom bar you mean an actual bar, but I couldn't find a way to do that)

Comment: I made a quick video, is this the functionality you're looking for? https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wwi0wo76supy72/2015-01-13_10-23-28.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Yes, and as you can see you can't resize the window by changing the height, just the width or both from the corner...

Comment: Ah sorry again.  Didn't think that was an actual problem so my brain misread the question.  Why do you want it to be able to resize horizontally?  I want to say it's just a bug with IB-- for 2 reasons: 1, if you set the aspect ratio on a custom view and resize horizontally it works.  And 2, if you try to resize horizontally, it moves the IB's canvas similar to if you were to resize a custom view.  So it looks like the canvas thinks it's resizing, but it's not actually.  I tried messing with the settings of the window but couldn't find a set that allowed for this functionality.  Sorry :\

Comment: Well, mostly is for consistency, why would a user be able to resize a window just from the side or the corner? Also, if I don't set the aspect ratio constraint but use -[NSWindow setAspectRatio:] resizing work as intended (but I can't actually use since my ratio is not fixed, due to the space at the bottom)

Comment: Okay i'm on the same page now.  How does this look? https://www.dropbox.com/s/bes38ff8scloh84/2015-01-13_11-28-08.mp4?dl=0

Comment: So for that, I did as you said and set the AspectRatio property on the NSWindow-- and in the IB I have 2 views.  They are both constrained to the bounds of the superview, and then the bottom of the top view to the top of the bottom view.  Would that view layout work for you?

Comment: It seems to be mostly working, but the window occasionally jumps around when dragging fast from the corner... I guess this might be the best it can get, it's weird that it works by setting a wrong aspect ratio on the window...

Comment: Yeah sorry I can't help you more.  I'm not sure how to make it better from that